# iOS: trying to access Firestore triggers EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore

Swift 4 project in Xcode 9.2

I'm trying to use Firestore in a project. I've added the libraries and cut and pasted the sample code from the FireStore intro guide. But I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and have not been able to figure out why. Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
    ref = db.collection("users").addDocument(data: [
        "first": "Ada",
        "last": "Lovelace",
        "born": 1815
    ]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error adding document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
        }
    }
```

And here's a screen dump of the error:

[image]

ANyone have an idea as to what's going wrong?

Comment: I've now found that the EXC_BAD_ACCESS was caused by not adding the certs bundle from the Firestore/Resources directory to the project. However I'm still having problems. 

Firestore appears to be creating the documents as a document id is assigned. But it doesn't appear in the Firebase web console and the completion block is never called.

Comment: Dam, it just crashed again. Just took a lot longer with a new error: `2018-01-05 00:08:37.051944+1100 Crux[23004:1412680] *** Assertion failure in -[FSTWriteStream closeWithFinalState:error:], third_party/firebase/ios/Source/Firestore/Source/Remote/FSTStream.m:348`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that the error was due to the database rules not allowing access. I opened up the rules to allow public read write and it's now working.

Comment: Nope, for me not helps, still same crash and database is opened for read and write for all.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem over here. Everything used to work fine untill the last iOS SDK update. If I write data to firestore they are not shown in console, sometimes after a few minutes or a hour.

App crashes on this message every few minutes:

> 2018-01-09 10:10:17.284630+0100 spontRestaurantAppIos[18971:19308343] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: closeWithFinalState should only be called for a started stream that has an active delegate.'

I've contacted firestore support and this is what I got back:

> Upon checking, this a known bug with our iOS SDK. This is now on our radar and our engineers are currently on it.
>
> For any updates, please watch out on our release notes.

So I guess we'll just have to wait... anybody have other suggestions?

Also see this issue in github:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/596

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I don't get a error for 4 minutes. Then it crashes with

```
2018-01-09 21:11:23.584982+1100 Crux[2671:334948] *** Assertion failure in -[FSTWriteStream closeWithFinalState:error:], third_party/firebase/ios/Source/Firestore/Source/Remote/FSTStream.m:348
```

Still no idea why.